# why do we need thunk.withExtraArgument?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering, redux-thunk

I currently have an issue with my code so while I am debugging i am trying to understand which approach shall I take in order to solve the issue.

I am using google oauth with passport.js. from client I have an action to fetch the authentication.

```
import axios from "axios";
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api",
  timeout: 3000,
});

export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  try {
    await axiosInstance.get("/auth/current_user").then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};
```

here is the client-side store set up:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  window.INITIAL_STATE, // 
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

and this is the server side store set up:

```
export default (req) => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  console.log("store from servre", store);
  return store;
};
```

Another approach would be instead of defining axiosInstance in action, i define it when I create the client side store and pass it to `thunk.withExtraArgument` iike this.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "/",
});
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  window.INITIAL_STATE,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(axiosInstance))
);
```

I changed the action accordingly:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  try {
    await api.get("/auth/current_user").then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};
```

My question which method should I use. CUrrently I have issue in both methods :) . But if i know which way is correct then I will solely focus on that method.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you go with with creating an instance of axios in a file and importing it whereever you need it, instead of adding it as an argument to thunk

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api",
  timeout: 3000,
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

---

actions.js

```
import api from '/path/to/api';

export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    await api.get("/auth/current_user").then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};
```

The advantage of the above solution is that you can import and use the instance for making direct API calls too in your components for which you do not need to dispatch actions to the reducers.